# How can I take Angular Component internal content as an input?

Tags: html, angular

I need to take the inner html of my custom component as an input or assign it as a variable.

for EX:

`<my-component>Hello There</my-component>`

how do I assign the "Hello There" as a variable inside my component?

i tried document.getElementById(id).innerHTML but it's not that great

Answer (score 1):

Recommend working through the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes) tutorial.

`document.getElementById` isn't something we do often (or ever really) in an angular application.

You can use `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside your `my-component` component template to project the content leaving the parent as you have in your question.

Or you can use an `@Input() message: string` input binding inside the component and pass the message to the child via

```html
<my-component message="Hello There"></my-component>

// or <my-component message="Hello There" /> if you're on latest angular
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I use inputs to bind the values but sometimes it's a template not just a string or an object, for some cases I add <ng-template #variable> and I pass the variable a input but it's annoying for small templates, I will use your recommendation of ng-content.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are better practices but you can use this aproach.

In your component, add a @ContentChild decorator to the variable where you want to assign the projected content.

```
...

  @ContentChild('content') content;

  ngAfterContentInit() { // this hook because content has to load first
    this.content.nativeElement.textContent  // <- you can access the content with this attribute
  }
...
```

```
<my-component>
  <span #content>Hello There</span>
</my-component>
```

In the example above, the @ContentChild decorator is assigned to content and uses the same name as the template reference variable #content.